# Why lambda takes variable's initial value

Tags: c++, lambda, stl

Question is why program print id:0, id:1, id:2, 42
instead of id:42, id:43, id:44, 45.

```
int main()
{

    int id = 0;
    auto f = [id] () mutable {
        std::cout << "id: " << id << std::endl;
        ++id; // OK
    };

    id = 42;
    f();
    f();
    f();
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking _why_ it is specified to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Because `id` is captured by value, i.e. it gets copied. And when the lambda is declared (i.e. when capture happens) `id` has the value of `0`.

You might want to change it to capture-by-reference.

```
auto f = [&id] () {
//        ^
    std::cout << "id: " << id << std::endl;
    ++id;
};
```

BTW: For this case `mutable` becomes superfluous.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OgnJvEP5EiYdifrZ)